# i am trying to write a simple mail program in java. What should i use. How do i configure my local machine to send mail?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am writing some application in which i need to send mails. My application is in JAVA so probably i will be using javamail. But i dont know how to use it and how to configure mail server from my local pc so that i can test if mails can be sent.Please suggest.

Comment: i realize that GMAIL SMTP is paid. Can somebody suggest something free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use GMAIL smtp to send mail.
Here is a sample snippet

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String from = "username";
    String pass = "password";
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    String[] to = {"to@gmail.com"}; // added this line

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

    // To get the array of addresses
    for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { // changed from a while loop
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

    for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
    message.setSubject("sending in a group");
    message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, from, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

Comment: any dependencies on google. Can i send mail to any email address.

Comment: @sushil bharwani, yes you can send it to any valid mail address, google's server will get use. that s the only dependency

Comment: can use i use google smtp server for production level code. Like i use it for sending mails by 20,000 employees. Sorry if i sound stupid.

Comment: @sushil bharwani , If you planning to send mail to client or user it won't look good if you will use gmail :) , you can have gmail for enterprise also it will give you @yourdomainname.com ,at last it is your choice

Comment: I didnt followed "It wont look good" lets say i am developing application for my company. The mails are send to companies clients and employees. What are the reasons i should not use GMAIL SMTP.

Comment: @sushil bharwani , if you are normal gmail user than you would probably have mail id something like `abc@gmail.com` if you use this mail id your client ,user will get this mail id as from field, and this doesn't look pretty professional :) I hope it is clear now

Comment: Yes thanks very much i followed. just to clarify u said the gmail will be able to give me @mydomain as well.

Comment: @sushil bharwani  Yes,You can get more info about that over here http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html,

Comment: @sushil bharwani No idea. probably they provide it free for limited account like in free version you will get around30 , i am not sure